# Nested AngularJS promises not working in unit tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am learning how to use AngularJS promises and I'm having a problem writing unit tests for them.  I wrote a module with a `factory` that can query for an RSS feed, parse the titles from the articles, and return a promise that will resolve an array of the title strings.

Here is the module code:

```
angular.module('rss', [])

.factory('rssService', ['$http', '$q', '$rootScope', function($http, $q, 
    $rootScope) {
  return function(url) {

    this.getTitles = function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer(),
        titles = [];

      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url
      }).success(function(data) {
        $(data).find('title').each(function(index, item) {
          var title = $(item).text();
          console.log(title);
          titles.push(title);
        });
        deferred.resolve(titles);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    };
  };
}])
;
```

And here is my Jasmine unit test code:

```
beforeEach(module('rss'));

describe("RSS Module", function() {

  var rssService, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_rssService_, _$httpBackend_) {
    rssService = new _rssService_('/rss');
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  }));

  it("Can parse an RSS Feed and get the titles", function(done) {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/rss').respond(mockRSS); // mock data declared earlier
    var titles =  rssService.getTitles();
    $httpBackend.flush();

    titles.then(function(data) {
      console.log("Done!");
      expect(data.length).toBe(17);
      done();
    });


  });
});
```

When I run the unit test, I get the following error:

`Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

Which is because, while my promise resolved, it did not make a call to `$apply` the changes.  The solution I've read about was to inject a `$rootScope` and call `$rootScope.$apply()`  after I resolve the promise.  Doing this though results in the following error

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

which is because I'm calling `$rootScope.$apply()` inside of the `success()` block, so a digest is already happening.

Outside of a unit test (using an actual RSS feed) the code works fine. The controller's scope handles the digest and things work as expected.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is right about the order of `flush` and `then`. The `flush` should be after the callbacks have been defined.

Also, when you're using `flush` from $httpBackend, or from $timeout, there is no need to use `done`: the test becomes synchronous. So the test can be:

```
it("Can parse an RSS Feed and get the titles", function() {
  $httpBackend.expectGET('/rss').respond(mockRSS); // mock data declared earlier
  rssService.getTitles().then(function(data) {
    expect(data.length).toBe(17);
  });
  $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

Also, I don't think directly related to your issue, but there isn't usually a need to manually create a promise when you want to post-process the result of `$http`. Using the `then` callback of `$http`, instead of the custom `success`, you can use standard promise chaining:

```
this.getTitles = function() {
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url
  }).then(function(response) {
    var derivedData = {length: response.data.length};
    return derivedData;
  });
};
```

You can see this at http://plnkr.co/edit/efTzOU9RYhVIgLVMdKkd .

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to move my line of code that flushed the `$httpBackend` to *after* the code to declare the `then` block. What was happening was the GET request was being flushed and my promise would be declared and resolved before I had given it a `then`.

The new unit test code looks like this:

```
it("Can parse an RSS Feed and get the titles", function(done) {
  $httpBackend.expectGET('/rss').respond(mockRSS);
  var titles =  rssService.getTitles();

  titles.then(function(data) {
    console.log("Done!");
    expect(data.length).toBe(17);
    done();
  });

  $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

I didn't have to change any of my actual module code, but I'm currious if there is a better way to write it using chained promises. Comments or additional answers are very welcome.

Comment: Hi @austin, to help people with the same problem in the future, it would be better to delete this question and ask a new one with the minimal information required to help people answer it.  (Assuming a similar question hasn't already been asked and answered.)

Comment: I had the same issue with a direct `resource.$save(callback)` where it gives the `$digest already in progress` when I call `$httpBackend.flush()`, but not when I do it after a `resource.get()`. Changing the order didn't help. Any ideas?